# How to have multiple Gemfiles for a project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

In my team, some people like to use the `pry-rails` gem and others don't like it.

Is there a way to have a secondary Gemfile for development where I don't commit it to git and is still read by `bundler`?

Comment: don't think its possible, but somehow you can hide it from git.

Comment: @Gabbar how to hide it from git?

Comment: @Shobhit I think he is taking about .gitignore

Comment: Why does it matter if the developers who don't like `pry-rails` have it installed? Is it causing a **conflict** with some other tool, that others want to use? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @TomLord It changes the `rails c` and some like it, some hate it.

Comment: I would suggest conditionally **requiring** it via an environment variable then, rather than conditionally including it in the Gemfile. The answer below has one big problem: Developers will keep updating the `Gemfile.lock` and accidentally checking it into source control!

Comment: @TomLord: that's a good suggestion

Comment: @Shobhit You've already settled on the solution of using a second Gemfile, but this isn't the right approach. You should generally ask how to solve the *underlying* problem you're having, rather than help with implementing a specific solution, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem.

Comment: @meagar That's why I haven't accepted any answer. I am still looking for a solution, but I've found a quick hack for the time being.

Comment: @Shobhit The real solution for your specific underlying problem with this gem is: Include `pry-rails` in your gemfile for everybody, and people who don't like it can explicitly suppress it with `export DISABLE_PRY_RAILS=1` in their `.bash_profile`. pry-rails already supports this opt-out, you don't need to introduce a second gemfile just to selectively include/exclude this gem.

Comment: @meagar Thank you so much!

Answer (score 10):

You can run:

```
BUNDLE_GEMFILE=/path/to/another/gemfile bundle install
```

Or in Gemfile (will create conflict with committed Gemfile.lock) :

```
gem 'pry-rails' if ENV['WITH_PRY']
```

And populate **WITH_PRY** env variable to enable pry.

Another solution to avoid Gemfile.lock conflict with Rails app :

```
# In Gemfile
group :dev_with_pry do
  gem 'pry-rails'
end
```

And add **dev_with_pry** to **RAILS_GROUPS** env variable, this will install the gem but not require it.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a good solution for my problem.

Comment: This is going to introduce some weird problems with `Gemfile.lock` that some developers are going to have to remember *not* to commit, as Tom Lord already pointed out above.

Comment: I added another solution to avoid Gemfile.lock conflict

Answer (score 0):

As per the specifications shared you can manage by having two gemfiles and requiring them based on environment.

```
Gemfile

source 'https://rubygems.org'
gemfiles = [ 'Gemfile1', 'Gemfile2' ]
gemfiles.each do |gemfile|
    instance_eval File.read(gemfile)
  end
end
```

Now you can have two separate Gemfile such as

Gemfile1

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'pry'
```

Then other gems can be added in Gemfile2

Gemfile 2

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
 gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

Hope it Helps!!